# Inserting in my database PHP and Angular JS

Tags: php, angularjs

Good day!!!
I'm having a problem with inserting inputted records to database.
Well the other inputted data are properly inserting at my database but three of the fields dont insert...
 I'm using PHP with Angualr Js

Here's the three fields that wont insert

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : addform.civil_status.$invalid && addform.civil_status.$dirty, 
        'has-success' : addform.civil_status.$valid && addform.civil_status.$dirty}">
<label for="civil_status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Civil Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<select name='civil_status' id='civil_status' class='form-control'>
<option value='1 - Married'>1 -  Married</option>
<option value='2 - Widowed'>2 - Widowed</option>
<option value='3 - Separated'>3 - Separated</option>
<option value='4 - Divorced'>4 - Divorced</option>
<option value='5 - Single'>5 - Single</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="addform.civil_status.$error" ng-if="addform.civil_status.$invalid && addform.civil_status.$dirty">
                            <p ng-message="required">Civil Status is required.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : addform.gender.$invalid && addform.gender.$dirty, 
        'has-success' : addform.gender.$valid && addform.gender.$dirty}">
  <label for="gender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">

  Male<input type='radio'  id='gender' name='gender' value='male' style='max-width:350px;' required='' autocomplete='off'>
  Female    <input type='radio'  id='gender' name='gender' value='female' style='max-width:350px;' required='' autocomplete='off'>
  <div class="help-block" ng-messages="addform.gender.$error" ng-if="addform.gender.$invalid && addform.gender.$dirty">
   <p ng-message="required">Gender is required.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : addform.birthdate.$invalid && addform.birthdate.$dirty, 
        'has-success' : addform.birthdate.$valid && addform.birthdate.$dirty}">
 <label for="birthdate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Birthdate</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">


   <select name='month
   <option>--Month--</option>
   <option value='January'>January</option>
   <option value='February'>February</option>
                        <option value='March'>March</option>
                        <option value='April'>April</option>
                        <option value='May'>May</option>
                        <option value='June'>June</option>
                        <option value='July'>July</option>
                        <option value='August'>August</option>
                        <option value='September'>September</option>
                        <option value='October'>October</option>
                        <option value='November'>November</option>
                        <option value='December'>December</option>
                        </select>

                        <select name='day'>
                        <option>--Day--</option>
                        <option value='1'>1</option>
                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                        <option value='4'>4</option>
                        <option value='5'>5</option>
                        <option value='6'>6</option>
                        <option value='7'>7</option>
                        <option value='8'>8</option>
                        <option value='9'>9</option>
                        <option value='10'>10</option>
                        <option value='11'>11</option>
                        <option value='12'>12</option>
                        <option value='13'>13</option>
                        <option value='14'>14</option>
                        <option value='15'>15</option>
                        <option value='16'>16</option>
                        <option value='17'>17</option>
                        <option value='18'>18</option>
                        <option value='19'>19</option>
                        <option value='20'>20</option>
                        <option value='21'>21</option>
                        <option value='22'>22</option>
                        <option value='23'>23</option>
                        <option value='24'>24</option>
                        <option value='25'>25</option>
                        <option value='26'>26</option>
                        <option value='27'>27</option>
                        <option value='28'>28</option>
                        <option value='29'>29</option>
                        <option value='30'>30</option>
                        <option value='31'>31</option>
                        </select>

                        <select name='year'>
                        <option>--Year--</option>
                        <option value='2015'>2015</option>
                        <option value='2014'>2014</option>
                        <option value='2013'>2013</option>
                        <option value='2012'>2012</option>
                        <option value='2011'>2011</option>
                        <option value='2010'>2010</option>
                        <option value='2009'>2009</option>
                        <option value='2008'>2008</option>
                        <option value='2007'>2007</option>
                        <option value='2006'>2006</option>
                        <option value='2005'>2005</option>
                        <option value='2004'>2004</option>
                        <option value='2003'>2003</option>
                        <option value='2002'>2002</option>
                        <option value='2001'>2001</option>
                        <option value='2000'>2000</option>
                        <option value='1999'>1999</option>
                        <option value='1998'>1998</option>
                        <option value='1997'>1997</option>
                        <option value='1996'>1996</option>
                        <option value='1995'>1995</option>
                        <option value='1994'>1994</option>
                        <option value='1993'>1993</option>
                        <option value='1992'>1992</option>
                        <option value='1991'>1991</option>
                        <option value='1990'>1990</option>
                        <option value='1989'>1989</option>
                        <option value='1988'>1988</option>
                        <option value='1987'>1987</option>
                        <option value='1986'>1986</option>
                        <option value='1985'>1985</option>
                        <option value='1984'>1984</option>
                        <option value='1983'>1983</option>
                        <option value='1982'>1982</option>
                        <option value='1981'>1981</option>
                        <option value='1980'>1980</option>
                        <option value='1979'>1979</option>
                        <option value='1978'>1978</option>
                        <option value='1977'>1977</option>
                        <option value='1976'>1976</option>
                        <option value='1975'>1975</option>
                        <option value='1974'>1974</option>
                        <option value='1973'>1973</option>
                        <option value='1972'>1972</option>
                        <option value='1971'>1971</option>
                        <option value='1970'>1970</option>
                        <option value='1969'>1969</option>
                        <option value='1968'>1968</option>
                        <option value='1967'>1967</option>
                        <option value='1966'>1966</option>
                        <option value='1965'>1965</option>
                        <option value='1964'>1964</option>
                        <option value='1963'>1963</option>
                        <option value='1962'>1962</option>
                        <option value='1961'>1961</option>
                        <option value='1960'>1960</option>
                        <option value='1959'>1959</option>
                        <option value='1958'>1958</option>
                        <option value='1957'>1957</option>
                        <option value='1956'>1956</option>
                        <option value='1955'>1955</option>
                        <option value='1954'>1954</option>
                        <option value='1953'>1953</option>
                        <option value='1952'>1952</option>
                        <option value='1951'>1951</option>
                        <option value='1950'>1950</option>
                        </select>                

                        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="addform.birthdate.$error" ng-if="addform.birthdate.$invalid && addform.birthdate.$dirty">
                            <p ng-message="required">Birthdate is required.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

PHP:

```
function Insert($model, $conn){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO employee_info 
        (emp_no, lname, fname, mname, birthdate, gender, department, position, civil_status, salary)
         VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($insertquery)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", 
            $model->emp_no, $model->lname, $model->fname, $model->mname, $model->birthdate, $model->gender, $model->department, $model->position, $model->civil_status, $model->salary);

        $stmt->execute();

        //add commit if simple insert does not work.
        $conn->commit();

        $stmt->close();
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: where is your php code to insert data in database ?

Comment: There I just added it..I've only post the three input form that I can't insert on my table

Comment: Do you use any php framework? Can you show what do you recieve at php side?

Comment: I'm just using AngularJS

Comment: These are the parameters that I only GET                                           action : insert
data[department] IT,
data[emp_no] 1013,
data[fname] Akeem,
data[lname] Romayla,
data[mname] T,
data[position] Programmer,
data[salary] 15,000

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my findings. Hope this may help you. With the shared items found only:- 
one tag is incomplete

```
<select name='month
```

if this is complete , then all these values will get in action page

can verify by printing the array of $_POST if action is POST

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
```

or

```
$postdata    = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($postdata);
```

And as it is in angular, if we are using angular models for form elements, it will be easy to see the values in front end itself

please refer https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Thank you